# Copy text to clip board

Tags: macos, vim, zsh

I'm currently writing a Makefile whose task is to copy the text content from a given file into the computer's actual clipboard.

One way I thought was to run vim with a special startup command (option -c 'command'). So I thought of using

```
vim -c '%w !pbcopy | q'
```

That doesn't work because !pbcopy prompts for a carriage return (I think). Anyway, at runtime Vim tells me

```
zsh:1: command not found: q

shell returned 127

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Sucks.

Any other way I could do that ? Either get around that carriage return problem in this double vim command, or simply find another way to copy my text from my terminal (I use Zsh).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Ok, it makes sense now : pbcopy is a command shell anyway (which I'm now discovering), and so ever after the bang (!) we're the shell. Which is why it's the shell that complains.
Now, how to use pbcopy correctly ?

Comment: I'd have though `cat your_filename | pbcopy` would do it...

Comment: @John3136 `pbcopy < your_filename` no need for `cat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Vim at all for this; what you're doing is equivalent to taking a trip around the world just to fetch the newspaper from the front porch.

To explain the Vim error: There are Vim commands that can be chained together, e.g. `:version | help`, but some commands can take arbitrary arguments (including the `|` command separator), so chaining is not directly possible. As you can see at `:help :|`, the `:write !` command is one of those. You can work around this by wrapping the command in `:execute` (which allows chaining):

```
:execute '%w !pbcopy' | q
```

Comment: Hah, excellent. Even though my question was stupid, you turned it into something interesting and informative. So, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

To quote `pbcopy(1)`:

> pbcopy takes the standard input and places it in the specified pasteboard. If no  pasteboard  is
>          specified,  the  general  pasteboard will be used by default.  The input is placed in the paste-
>          board as plain text data unless it begins with the Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) file header  or
>          the  Rich  Text Format (RTF) file header, in which case it is placed in the pasteboard as one of
>          those data types.

So you just have to do the command `pbcopy < file`

Become familiar with the Unix command `man` which give you access to the manual pages for commands. When you are familiar with it then it is easy to get the answer to such questions as these for yourself.

Comment: Funny thing is, I'm in no way new to Unix or Vi. What I am new to, is being stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xclip :

```
cat file | xclip -i -selection clipboard
```